# Webpage load time issue. wget showing "HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently"

Tags: linux, apache, dns, web, wget

I have two websites on the same server. Both use Magento template. I am bit confused about the load time of both.

Please see the image.! https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZteYv.png

They both use same DNS server and the above result is from the server itself.

One is loading in 5-6 sec but other take more than 10 sec.

What is mean by "HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently". Is that causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a "301 Moved Permanently" then one of the resources of your page is being returned with a header that is a permanent redirect to another server (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Note that that could be caused by a component that you have little control over such as a framework or and widget that is coming from a CDN like jQuery, webfonts, bootstrap, social widgets, etc.

To find the offending resource, first clear your browser cache, then open the Developer Tools of your browser of choice, open the Network tab, then reload the page.  Scroll through the resources and it should be obvious which is causing the delay and/or redirect.